# How can I remove the blank spaces after a Page Footer in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report that shows a banner on the first page and will be hidden afterwards. However, on the second page, there is a large amount of blank space left that is the size of the banner. Is there a way to remove this?

I am using a Page Footer A and Page Footer B. Page Footer A contains the banner images and Page Footer B contains a "Page n of N". Page Footer A will be supressed after page 1 while Page Footer B will show after page 1.

[image]

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I suggest you to set your banner in the `Report Header` section ;).

Comment: You could just place you banner on a different section.

Answer (score 0):

CR will always reserve white space when conditionally suppressed. I have seen this talked about many times. Try this website for some work-arounds.

http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/128